# E4 RCP CTabFolder image drop shadow

Tags: css, image, rcp, e4, dropshadow

E4 RCP Application: I have a png image with alpha in my CTabFolder.  However my CTabFolder swt-select-tab-fill: rgb(20, 20, 20); this is very dark.  I'd like to add a white drop shadow to the image I have in this to allow it to stand out when the CTabFolder is selected and normal when unselected.  I've been looking for such a css tag for this folder but haven't had any luck.  Any idea on what I might use or where I can find ALL of the CSS tags available for E4 RCP CSS usage?

Thanks in advance for your help,

-Marv

Comment: There isn't any support for a drop shadow.

Comment: Thanks greg449.. Do you know if there is any support for "inverting" images color?  So I can change the Images color to invert over the darker background on the CTabFolder when the CTabFolder is selected?

Comment: Tab folder items only support one image and there is nothing that will change it on selection or mouse over. You can specify a tab folder renderer in the CSS but this requires you to write the renderer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end as greg-449 suggested, I could not use CSS to do this.  So I used an IPartListener added to the to the end of each of the e4 part's:

> @PostConstruct     public void createControls(Composite parent)
>
> {
>
> ...
>
> partService.addPartListener(new ChangeIconPartListener());
>
> }

method and used E4's PartService to update set the part.setIconURL() using the inverted png image.

NOTE: ChangeIconPartListener is a simple java class that implements IPartListner interface.

I use the

> public void partActivated(MPart part)

and

> public void partVisible(MPart part)

methods to check the part's elementId and then set's the iconURI to the inverted image in stored in my applications icons folder. for each part I want to change the tab's image on.

I used a switch statement to check the part.getElementId() and for each part image I wanted to change, I changed the image using the setIconURI method as in:

> part.setIconURI("platform:/plugin/my_own_UI_Plugin/icons/someImageInverted.png");

Would have been nice to be enabled do this in CSS, but this will work fine and the IPartListener's abilities might be useful for other events when the part state changes from partActivated, partDeactivated, partVisible, partHidden, partBroughtToTop etc.